# Check if value is maximum/minimum of previous, current and next value

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series data frame, and I want to list the days when in three consecutive days, **High** was the highest the **second day** and the same thing but the value of **Low** was the lowest the **second day**.
I tried these two lines but I hardcoded the date after viewing the data. I want to know if there is a way to not hardcode it.

`df_highest = df.loc['1986-03-17':'1986-03-19', 'High'].max()`

`df_lowest= df.loc['1986-03-24':'1986-03-26', 'Low'].min()`

Here's a piece of data.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend changing your title to something more specific of this question, such as: 'Check if value is maximum/minimum of previous, current and next value'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `diff` function combined with greater than (`gt`) or less than (`lt`):

```
(df['High'].diff().gt(0)) & (df['High'].diff(-1).gt(0))

(df['Low'].diff().lt(0)) & (df['Low'].diff(-1).lt(0))
```

In you screenshot example this will only lead to a Series of False values.

You can also use greater or equal (`ge`) or less or equal (`le`), if you also want to return True if the second day has a value equal to the day before/after.

For example with High value on day 1986-03-17 which is equal to the next value of High on 1986-03-18. Or Low on 1986-03-24/1986-03-25.

This will create a True value for the mentioned Dates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I had almost the same idea in mind, but didn't find a function for it! The diff function is brilliant.